# How to programmatically add elements to toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm currently making an app with backwards support for toolbars, and thus I have this file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I then programatically add it in to the views by doing something like:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

However, I want to be able to add custom views into the Toolbar, such as EditText and TextView's without hard-coding them into the toolbar.xml above.

Is there any way to do this? It might be worth noting that I'm using the V7 support library.

Thanks,
Liam

Comment: You could always add them to the XML and show or hide them dynamically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just give a try to the following

**Step 1 : Add `LinearLayout` to the toolbar in xml file**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <LinearLayout
           android:id=@+id/toolbar_item_container
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Step 2 : Get this `LinearLayout` in code**

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_transaction);
LinearLayout layoutToolbar = (LinearLayout)
                  mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_item_container);
```

**Step3 : Add and Remove view to this `LinearLayout` using following code**

```
layoutToolbar.addView();
layoutToolbar.removeView();
```

> This can be done without `LinearLayout` also, by directly adding and removing elements from `Toolbar`. You can try both the ways.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm this works for both attaching to the layout and directly to the toolbar.

However, I can only seem to add views by constructing them at runtime. Any idea how I'd inflate/attach a custom XML view to the toolbar/layout?

Comment: Using same way as I mentioned above..using addView method. And inflate element using LayoutInflater class.

Comment: I've used the code: View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.homescreentoolbar, toolbar, false);
toolbar.addView(v);, but the text of the view does not seem to show. :/

Comment: Okay so all this code works with the Linear Layout, but it doesn't show for directly adding to the toolbar. However, it solves my issue and keeps flexibility in your file. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have toolbar in xml, can set custom view programmatically

```
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_view);
    View view = actionBar.getCustomView();
    TextView locationTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_toolbar);
    locationTitle.setText("some text");
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```